# Loop categorienames and their subcat names on productpage in Magento

Tags: php, loops, magento, magento-1.9

I made a small script that loops all categories a product belongs to on a product page. Like this:

[image]

My issue is that all categories are shown in one big list while they all come from a certain amount of top categories. For example for the image shown, all categories come from `allergenen` `intoleranties` and `voedingsstijlen`. The customer doesn't see this.

I would like to split the list and show the top categorie the sub categories belong to like this:

[image]

So I guess I first need to get all parentids from the categories then with those ids I need to get all the top categorie names, loop them, and inside that loop I loop the subcategories.

How would I do that in magento structured code?
The first image is shown with the following code:

```
<?php
// Haal alle categorieen op waar het product onder valt
$currentCatIds      = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('url')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
->addIsActiveFilter();


$sorted = sort($categoryCollection);

$catlist .= '<ul class="categorielijst">';
foreach ($categoryCollection as $cat) {
    if ($cat->getName() != 'Root') {
        $catlist .= ' 
         <li><a href="' . $cat->getUrl() . '">' . $cat->getName() . '</a></li>';
    }
}
$catlist .= '</ul>';
echo $catlist;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('level',2)
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('url');
$out = "<ul>";
    foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
        $children = $cat->getChildren();
        $out .= "<li>";
        $out .= "<a href='".$cat->getUrl()."'>".$cat->getName()."</a>";
            $out .="<ul class='sub'>";
            foreach($children as $child){
                $ChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child);
                $out .="<li><a href='".$ChildModel->getUrl()."'>".$ChildModel->getName()."</a></li>";
            }
            $out .="</ul>";
        $out .= "</li>";
    }
    $out .= "</ul>";
    echo $out;
```

Comment: Is this correct code for magento 1.9? Only the top categories load with thise code, not the children <ul class="sub"></ul> is empty.

Comment: Its's working on my end you just need to fatch 2nd level of category from that you can get all main categories(addFieldToFilter('level',2)) and after that you can get all it's child categorie through Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(--CHILDREN ID--);